# Laravel setup Cors for instagram resources

Tags: laravel, apache, cross-origin-resource-policy

when I try to show `instagram` images on our web application i get this error:

```
The resource at “https://scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150
/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com&
_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=B7qUhQC8GZkAX9zaHp6&edm=APwHDrQBAAAA&ccb=7-4&
oh=00_AT8PPmyxQt8DqIAf8z4oKqY1VKWSX0Gh04M_pcVFDltIHQ&oe=61D10099&_nc_sid=1c538d” 
was blocked due to its Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header (or lack thereof). 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)#
```

`html` tag:

```html
<img 
   src="https://scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=B7qUhQC8GZkAX9zaHp6&edm=APwHDrQBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8PPmyxQt8DqIAf8z4oKqY1VKWSX0Gh04M_pcVFDltIHQ&oe=61D10099&_nc_sid=1c538d" 
   crossorigin="anonymous" alt="">
```

after implementing and setting up `Laravel Cors` i get error again, my `Laravel Cors` configuration is:

```php
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

and we also use `apache2` web server on local

Comment: Any feedback on the answer you got? Did it solve your problem? If so, please accept it. If not, explain what's missing.

Comment: @jub0bs as we know, we should configure apache server to resolve this issue, and we don't have any issue on mobile application which we implemented recently

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. Did you try looking up [cross-origin resource policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP))?

> Cross-Origin Resource Policy is a policy set by the `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` HTTP header that lets web sites and applications opt in to protection against certain requests from other origins (such as those issued with elements like `<script>` and `<img>`), to mitigate speculative side-channel attacks, like Spectre, as well as Cross-Site Script Inclusion attacks.

Sending a GET request to the resource in question returns a response that
contains the following [`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy):

```http
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
```

As a result, supporting browsers block no-cors cross-origin requests to the the image in question. It can only be loaded from the same origin, i.e. `https://scontent-dus1-1.cdninstagram.com`. Setting up CORS on your server will not help.

One solution would be to serve a copy of the image from a domain you control—under the assumption that you're legally allowed to do that.